# Dimension dependencies of a nested triangle in a trapezoid.

Tags: geometry

I am trying to find a dependency of angle Alpha if O value is a variable.
O, D, H - known values.
Alpha = function of O.
Does anybody have any idea please?
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Will it be correct to say that the two cuts of the pipe are not with the same angel?

Comment: Are you still looking for answer?

Comment: The vertical cut angle of the longer pipe will change if Alpha changes. Alpha will change as soon as the O custom distance is changed. Diameter D is the stock size of the pipe used to weld this connection, it never changes. Offset H is also a given specification value, therefore it is a known initial value which stays the same and never changes.

Comment: It seems to be a practical problem where you try to attach two pipes. The equations you get require somewhat high level of math (as I got it). Will a graphical approach using GeoGebra be helpful?

Comment: What are typical values for D, H, O?

Comment: The given dimensions are D=8, H=25, O=20, we need to find Alpha using trigonometry. By using Autocad I found Alpha to be 62.83 degrees.

Comment: Based on my attempt the equations you are deriving are requiring complicated math.